# Ari Image Slider, External path

Tags: php, joomla, module, slider, joomla2.5

Is it posible to request an image of an external link to use it on the Ari image slider joomla module? something like this in the image path:

```
Http://random.com/image.png
```

instead of

```
images/something.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

If the slider is a module check the module `default.php` inside your module `tmpl` folder
instead of loading `../images/img.png` to use like.

```
<img src="<?php echo JURI::root()?>images/img.png" />
```

Hope its helps..